# Prevent error from halting a Python script

Tags: python

Using Python 2.6, the following error occurs when I run the far below script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g.py", line 7, in <module>
    results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 261, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.getdata(params=params))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 223, in getdata
    raise GeocoderError(j['status'], url)
pygeocoder.GeocoderError: Error ZERO_RESULTS
Query: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=&sensor=false&bounds=&language=&address=%22++A+FAKE+ADDRESS
```

The Python 2.6 script:

```
import csv, string
from pygeocoder import Geocoder

with open('file.csv') as goingGeo:
        theSpreadsheet = csv.reader(goingGeo, quotechar=None)
        for row in theSpreadsheet:
                results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
                (lat, long) = results[0].coordinates
                with open('geo_file.csv', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(row[0] + ",")
                        f.write(row[1] + ",")
                        f.write(row[2] + ",")
                        f.write(row[3] + ",")
                        f.write(row[4] + ",")
                        f.write(row[5] + ",")
                        f.write(row[6] + ",")
                        f.write(row[7] + ",")
                        try:
                                f.write(str(lat))
                        except GeocoderError:            
                                pass
                        f.write(",")
                        try:
                                f.write(str(long))
                        except GeocoderError:            
                                pass
                        f.write('\n')
```

I just want the script to continue even with the error.

Thank you!

Comment: It helps if you put the `try`/`catch` around the part of your code that actually raises the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have try/except blocks around a `write` call that can't possibly throw a GeoCoderError, but you don't have a try/except around the call to `geocoder()` that can (and apparently does) throw that error.  You probably want something like:

```
try:
    results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
    (lat, long) = results[0].coordinates
except GeocoderError:
    (lat, long) = (0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that explanation made sense! I did the following: 

`for row in theSpreadsheet:
                try:
                        results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
                        (lat, long) = results[0].coordinates
                except:
                        (lat, long) = (0.0, 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the try-except-finally statement like this:

```
try:
    f.write(str(lat))
except GeocodeError:
    pass
finally:
    do_something_else_regardless_of_above
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the `try: except GeocoderError` parts, but they're in the wrong places. You need to move them to wrap the `Geocoder.geocode` call, since that's what is throwing the error:

```
        for row in theSpreadsheet:
                try:
                        results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
                except GeocoderError:
                        continue
                (lat, long) = results[0].coordinates
```

Also note that you'll need to `import` the `GeocoderError` name from `pygeocoder`. Also, `long` is a keyword in Python, so I would suggest picking a different name for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#starting from line 6:
for row in theSpreadsheet:
        try:
            results  = Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
        except:
            pass
#rest of script . . .
```

you can also use "except" to deal with specific errors 
ex.

```
try:
    results=Geocoder.geocode(row[0])
except GeocodeError:
    #deal with error
```